# $_GET global scope in function as not global?

Tags: php, get, global-variables

I am trying to add something to the $_GET array in a function, but not have it add that value to $_GET outside of the function. I don't really understand scopes. Is there a way I can add scope local to the $_GET in the function to let php know I don't want a global update of the array?

Please assist

```
function url($toSort) {
        $_GET['sortby'] = "$toSort"; echo http_build_query($_GET);

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can also use an expression here `http_build_query(array("sortby"=>$tosort)+$_GET)` if you just need that result.

Comment: $_GLOBAL is super global variable you can't make it local

Answer (score 0):

Because $_GET is a superglobal, you can't change it wthout affecting it globally.

But why not simply take a local copy to "use" inside your function:

```
function url($toSort) {
    $localGet = $_GET;
    $localGet['sortby'] = $toSort; 
    echo http_build_query($localGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning the fundamentals, that did make perfectly good sense.